# Failure in VM deployment with ARM template while using existing storage account

Tags: ruby, azure-resource-manager

The Deployment of ARM template for creating a new VM was successful when new storage account was created. But on using existing storage account it failed with the following error.

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.8/gems/ms_rest_azure-0.1.1/lib/ms_rest_azure/azure_service_client.rb:72:in `get_put_operation_result': Long running operation failed with status Failed (MsRestAzure::AzureOperationError)

The same was observed in portal with status as failed and all the resources been provisioned

Answer (score 0):

I would try tweeting @AzureSupport on this one.

Comment: If you didn't get anything from @AzureSupport, try this: https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade